# Link Generation using discord.net

Tags: discord.net

anyone can help me out on this one. How would I go about generating an invite link through c# code?
I've been trying for a while now but can't get any progress and can't seem to find any resources about it.

any help is appreciated!!

**thanks**

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow won't write your code for you. instead, edit your question to illustrate (a) what *specifically* you've tried (at a code level), and (b) where *specifically* you're getting stuck in that attempt (along with all applicable error messages, expected vs. actual behaviors, etc.). Please also edit your question to conform to Stack Overflow's [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. If you need requirements developed into a solution, you should hire a developer (Stack Overflow does not facilitate such arrangements directly).

Comment: If it's a guild invite, there is a CreateInvite method on channel objects. If it's an invite for the bot, that's generated in the Discord Developer Portal